# Pen and marker using PowerPoint 2010 interop

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm new to PowerPoint interop and I'm trying to draw **red pen** and **yellow text marker** (not shapes!!!) lines while in presentation mode.

UPDATE:

I can draw a line like this:

```
settings = presentation.SlideShowSettings; 
window = settings.Run(); 
window.View.DrawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
```

But the line will always be black and thin. How can I select the red pen or yellow text marker for it?

Aside from the DrawLine method, I can select the pen for the user (mouse cursor becomes a pen instead of arrow) by setting:

```
window.View.PointerType = PpSlideShowPointerType.ppSlideShowPointerPen;
window.View.PointerColor.RGB = 255;
```

But how can I set it to text marker? yellow would be 65535, how do I get the text marker style (bigger pen, transparency) instead of the tiny solid pen?

Comment: If there's only one slideshow window, wouldn't it be `SlideShowWindows[0]`?

Comment: I tried [0] but it resulted in an exception telling me I should pick an index between 1 and 1 ... so apparently it's not zero based ...

Comment: Ppl, bounty is ending soon, is there really no way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a WPF window that is transparent and topmost (EDIT: do not maximize window)

   ```
   <Window ... Background="#00000000" Topmost="True" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="NoResize">
   ```
2. (NEW) Use GetWindowRect to get the location and size of the slide show window

   ```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT lpRect);
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   private struct RECT
   {
       public int Left;
       public int Top;
       public int Right;
       public int Bottom;
   }
   ```
3. Place the transparent window over the PowerPoint slideshow window

   ```
   settings = presentation.SlideShowSettings;
   slideshowWindow = settings.Run();

   RECT rect = new RECT();
   GetWindowRect(new IntPtr(slideshowWindow.HWND), ref rect);        
   overlayWindow.Left = rect.Left; // EDIT: do not use slideshowWindow.Left, etc.
   overlayWindow.Top = rect.Top;
   overlayWindow.Width = rect.Width;
   overlayWindow.Height = rect.Height;
   ```
4. Put a Canvas into the WPF window and add Polyline objects to it as needed. Text marker lines could be like this:

   ```
   line = new Polyline
   {
       Opacity = 0.8,
       Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow),
       StrokeThickness = 20
   };
   this.canvas.Children.Add(line);
   ```

   Add points to line.Points as needed. Call `this.canvas.Children.Clear()` to clear all your drawings.

It's a workaround but I'd say your best shot.

Comment: I tried it, but the overlay window always appears on the primary screen ... what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, it seems to have problems with the maximized window and the position of the slideshowWindow seems wrong. I edited my answer, this way it will work on any screen

Answer (score 2):

My sample application begins with creating an instance of a `PowerPoint.Application` class;

`PowerPoint.Application PowerPointApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();`

Then I set `Visible` property to `msoTrue`;

```
PowerPointApplication.Visible = Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

Then create a `Presentation` and `Slide`;

```
PowerPoint.Presentations PowerPointPresentationSet = PowerPointApplication.Presentations;

PowerPoint._Presentation PowerPointPresentation = PowerPointPresentationSet.Add();
PowerPoint.Slides PowerPointSlideSet = PowerPointPresentation.Slides;

PowerPoint._Slide PowerPointSlide = PowerPointSlideSet.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);
```

In my code, I created a `Shape` object;

```
PowerPoint.Shape PowerPointShape = PowerPointSlide.Shapes.AddLine(100, 100, 500, 500);
```

Then, I format it like this;

```
PowerPointShape.Line.Weight = 10;
PowerPointShape.Line.ForeColor.RGB = 65535;

PowerPointShape.Line.Transparency = 0.8f;
```

The point is, `Opacity` grows when `Transparency` property decreases.

You can set `Line.Weight` property to *thinner* or *ticker* the line, and you can set the value of `Foreground.RGB` property to change the color of line.

PS: I added these *namespaces* code files *usings* area;

```
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Core = Microsoft.Office.Core;
```

You can find working solution from this link; http://snipt.org/nsgk7

Comment: Yes, I did that too as a quick workaround, but I have 3 issues with that: 1. Drawing shapes instead of marker is really slow in a decent sized presentation (you can see the shapes created, the weight adjusted, the color set, etc.) 2. After this I have real shapes in my presentation, I would prefer the markers and the question if you want to keep or loose the annotation. And 3. If I use this in two presentations with different themes the shapes will look different (e.g. a round pen or a rectangular one) ...

Comment: I edited the question to emphasize that I'm looking for the markers, not for shapes. But thanks for your answer.